# VBA get dynamically names of component?

Tags: vba

I am newbie in vb and I am trying to write simple programs in Excel 2010.
I have a multipage with customers(cutomer1, customer2, ..., customer20)
For each customer I have 10 users "labels" with their textboxes.
The textboxes are filled from a sheet page customer1 B9:B18 , customer2 D9:D18, etc ...

Is there any way to get dynamically the names and the values in order to avoid code like the following ?

```
CUSTOMER1_USER1_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B9").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER2_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B10").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER3_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B11").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER4_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B12").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER5_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B13").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER6_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B14").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER7_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B15").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER8_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B16").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER9_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B17").Value
CUSTOMER1_USER10_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B18").Value

CUSTOMER2_USER1_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D9").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER2_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D10").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER3_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D11").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER4_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D12").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER5_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D13").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER6_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D14").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER7_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D15").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER8_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D16").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER9_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D17").Value
CUSTOMER2_USER10_TEXTBOX.Value = Sheets("Data").Range("D18").Value
```

......

Could you help me please do it ?

Thanks

Comment: what is a "multipage"? Are labels and textboxes in a UserForm or are they sheet controls?

Comment: @user3598756, here's some info on UserForm MultiPage controls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278699.aspx

Comment: Multipage is a component in vb like a panel with tabs.
Yes the labels and textboxes are in a UserForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    With Sheets("Data")
        For i = 1 To 20
            For j = 1 To 10
                Me.Controls("CUSTOMER" & i & "_USER" & j & "_TEXTBOX").Value = .Cells(j+8, 2*i).Value
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it could be wrapped in a `With Sheets("Data")` - `End With` block

Comment: @user3598756 Good idea. In this case the time savings is probably negligible but it makes the code cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: yes, it was just a matter of showing good coding practice that I very well know you know but is always good to show